# Understanding scope and shadowing matches

Tags: rust

I'm trying to improve on the final [guessing game sample code](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/book/guessing-game.html) a bit. Particularly, I plan to output "Please input a number!" if the user does not input a number rather than "Please input your guess." again. I'm doing this with an inner loop.  The code below does work:

```
let guess: u32;

loop {
    let mut guess_str = String::new();
    io::stdin().read_line(&mut guess_str)
        .ok()
        .expect("Failed to read line");

    guess = match guess_str.trim().parse() {
        Ok(num) => num,
        Err(_) => {
            println!("Please input a number!");
            continue;
        }
    };
    break;
}
```

I'd like to avoid the `guess_str` if I can by properly shadowing the matches. If I change `guess_str` to `guess`, Rust complains of `` use of possibly uninitialized variable: `guess` ``. I'm not sure how the variable could possibly be uninitialized if it's impossible for it to not be uninitialized with the code above. Is there any way to do this only using `guess`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let's look at a simpler reproduction:

```
fn make_guess() -> u32 {
    let guess;

    {
        let mut guess;
        guess = 1;
    }

    guess
}
```

Here, you create an outer variable `guess` and then shadow it inside the block. When you assign the value `1` to `guess`, you are assigning to the **inner** variable. The **outer** variable is never set to anything, thus you end up with the "use of possibly uninitialized variable" error.

> Is there any way to only use one variable

Indirectly, yes. I'd extract the code to a function. When you have a successful guess, you can simply `return`. Otherwise you allow the loop to occur:

```
fn make_guess() -> u32 {
    loop {
        let mut guess = String::new();
        io::stdin().read_line(&mut guess)
            .ok()
            .expect("Failed to read line");

        match guess.trim().parse() {
            Ok(num) => return num,
            Err(_) => {
                println!("Please input a number!");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This avoids the shadowing completely, avoids having to use an explicit `continue`, and adds a small amount of abstraction and organization to your code.

Comment: Okay, that makes a lot of sense. Not sure why I didn't see that before. Is there any way to only use one variable in my example?