# Using the index from enumerate outside the loop block

Tags: for-loop, scope, rust, enumerate

Consider this example of solving [Advent of Code 2015 1.2](https://adventofcode.com/2015/day/1).

```
fn main() {
    // advent of code 1.2 2015
    // you are at floor 0
    // if instruction is ) go one floor up, else go one floor down
    // what index has the character that makes you go below floor 0

    let instruction = ")))(((()))))";
    let mut floor = 0;

    for (i, c) in input.chars().enumerate() {
        if c.to_string() == ")" {
            floor += 1;
        } else {
            floor -= 1;
        }
        if floor < 0 {
            break;
        }
    }

    // will fail
    println!("floor: {}", i)
}
```

How can `i` be accessed outside the loop block?

Having read [Understanding scope and shadowing matches](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33422543/understanding-scope-and-shadowing-matches) and [this chapter of the book](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/first-edition/variable-bindings.html), I understand **why** my code fails, but I can't figure out how to deal with it and use `i` outside the block.

Is my problem that I have not understood the purpose of scopes in Rust? Should I put the loop inside of a function and return `i` if I want to use it outside the loop's scope?

Comment: Karl, it is okay to ask a separate question, but it's confusing to rewrite one question into a different question.

Comment: @DietrichEpp I understand this - but the question remains the same "Using the index from enumerate outside the loop block". And given the sole answer I got I understood my example made it look like I was asking for a way to find the index of `d` in the alphabet, whereas this was just an example.

Comment: Okay, from context I think you're right about that. I've reverted the rollback.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need to put the code in a function to get `i`, you could just assign it to a new variable:

```
fn main() {
    let instruction = ")))(((()))))";
    let mut floor = 0;
    let mut breaking_index = None;

    for (i, c) in instruction.chars().enumerate() {
        if c.to_string() == ")" {
            floor += 1;
        } else {
            floor -= 1;
        }
        if floor < 0 {
            breaking_index = Some(i);
            break;
        }
    }

    // will not fail
    println!("floor: {:?}", breaking_index)
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You **cannot** access a loop variable outside of the loop's scope. This isn't a "problem" unique to Rust; most programming languages in use today have similar scoping rules that would result in the same problem.

---

To solve your [first version of the problem](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/49390902/2), you should "return" the index, but you don't need a function for that. Instead, you can use iterator adapters:

```
fn main() {
    let maze = "***#***";

    let i = maze
        .chars()
        .enumerate()
        .find(|&(_, c)| c == '#')
        .map(|(i, _)| i);

    println!("# is at position: {:?}", i) // Some(3)
}
```

Note that this returns an `Option` to handle the case where the letter was not found.

---

To solve your [second version of the problem](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/49390902/5), you should "return" the index, but you don't need a function for that. Instead, you can use iterator adapters:

```
fn main() {
    let instruction = ")))(((()))))";
    let mut floor = 0;

    let i = instruction
        .chars()
        .enumerate()
        .find(|&(_, c)| {
            if c == ')' {
                floor += 1;
            } else {
                floor -= 1;
            }

            floor < 0
        })
        .map(|(i, _)| i);

    println!("floor: {:?}", i) // Some(6)
}
```

Note that this returns an `Option` to handle the case where the floor was not found.

---

Of course, you can choose to use a function and return early. Do whatever is understandable for you.

Comment: Thanks - but I realise I should have made it more clear that I need to loop through the characters. I have updated the code example in the question.

Comment: @KarlAnka editing the question to invalidate existing answers is *highly* frowned upon. Your edits have made it so that my answer is completely nonsensical and it would be reasonable for people to downvote it for being unhelpful.

Comment: Shepmaster... I don't think this answer actually addresses the question as it was *originally* written, before the edit. Karl is asking how to access a loop variable outside a loop, not asking you to give a better solution to the piece of code that happens to be used as an example.

Comment: I'm sorry for this. However, I don't think this answers my question why I updated the example to one where a loop is needed. Finding index of `d` in that broken alphabet was just a simple example.

Comment: @DietrichEpp The very first sentence of my answer is "You cannot access a loop variable outside of the loop's scope.". That 100% answers the question asked. Anything beyond, by necessity, must be "a better solution", since the posited solution is impossible.

Comment: @DietrichEpp do you believe that the updated version of the answer is  significantly better now that it has applied the same logic a second time?

Comment: While it's helpful to guide people to produce more idiomatic Rust code, there is a very obvious, simple, and correct alternative which only requires changing three lines of code. The alternative is so obvious, it's downright suspicious that it's absent from this answer. Of course the posited solution is impossible... that's why the OP has asked a question here. We can either interpret the question as, "How can I use the value from a for loop outside the block?" or, "Please rewrite my code using idiomatic Rust."

Comment: In the end, I feel that this answer serves more to showcase your skills at writing idiomatic Rust code, and does not give OP any of the tools they are lacking to solve similar problems in the future.